# Open terminal on start in a specific place and size

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, terminal, boot

I want that each time I login to my account (Ubuntu-desktop) a Terminal will open in a specific location and in a specific size.
In which file do I put the command, and what is the command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The command is:

> gnome-terminal  --geometry=widthxheight+Xposition+Yposition

Add it under System -> Preferences ->Startup applications.

Comment: Where is System?

Comment: @hello_there_andy: Maybe System settings? I am on Linux mint and it is called `System settings`

Answer (score 8):

```
--geometry GEOMETRY
```

Specifies the startup geometry for this terminal. The geometry specifies the desired width and height in terminal characters. For example: `--geometry=80x40` will create an eighty-column by forty-line terminal. You can also specify the location of the terminal Window on the screen; for example, `--geometry=80x40+100+200` will create a Window whose top left corner is 100 pixels to the right and 200 pixels down from the top left corner of the screen, while `--geometry=80x40+100-200` will give a Window whose bottom left corner is 100 pixels to the right and 200 pixels up from the bottom left corner of the screen.

[Source](http://multignometerm.sourceforge.net/web/doc/options.html)

Example: `gnome-terminal --geometry=80x40+100+200`

To make it so it always keep that setting:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/vte/termcap/xterm
```

Locate something simliar to:

```
:co#80:it#8:li#24:\
```

`co` is column number and `li` is row number.

Not sure how to change the location in that file though, sorry.

Comment: Under Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Trusty Tahr, the position seems to have the origin top-left, so the example above would show the window 100 pixels to the right and 200 pixels DOWN from the TOP left corner of the screen.

Comment: How to control the monitor number?

Comment: if you want to open on a sub monitor, `starting X location` would be `width of main + x location on sub`